# Is Front Row included with Lion?

Tags: macos, front-row

I was trying to use Front Row on Lion and I couldn't seem to find it. Is it included with Lion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Front Row is not included with OS X Lion. Apple dropped support for it when Lion came out. However, you can get it back by following [this 9 to 5 Mac article.](http://9to5mac.com/2011/07/19/os-x-lion-kills-front-row-heres-how-to-get-it-back/) You can download the Front Row application [here.](http://www.mac-hatter.com/blog/frontrowenablerforlion)